# Android: Update status to twitter

Tags: android, post, twitter, hyperlink

I'm a beginner with twitter4j,
I following http://twitter4j.org/en/configuration.html 
But i don't know what string should I put in setOAuthAccessToken() and setOAuthAccessTokenSecret()
Code:

```
//Config
    ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
            .setOAuthConsumerKey("consumer key here")
            .setOAuthConsumerSecret(
                    "consumer secret key here")
            .setOAuthAccessToken(
                    "access token here")//what is this
            .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("access token secret here");//what is this
    TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
    Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();

    //post to twitter
    try {
        twitter.updateStatus("aaaaaa");
    } catch (TwitterException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Is there any good tutorial for twitter on android. My only purpose is update a status to twitter.
Thanks.

Comment: // try this may be this help but i am not sure :  SharedPreferences prefs;                        String token = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, "");                                
   String secret = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, "");

Comment: Hi @Cropper. Thanks for you reply. I have just try this, but what is "OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN" and "OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET".

Comment: its in signpost-core jar file . you are using signpost-core jar file.

Comment: Why didn't dev.twitter have a good document? I have do the same with facebook API, its document seem to be more clearly.

Comment: ya if they didn'd provide what we can do ur problem is solved or not?

Comment: Thanks, I turn my way to use third party library which I dont want.

Answer (score 0):

oAuthAccessToken and oAuthAccessTokenSecret are the strings returned by Twitter when you authorize your application in the redirect url. After successful authorization, you should capture these from the redirect url. Below is the code extract from one of my project:

```
if (url != null && url.startsWith(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL)) //TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL is redirect url 
{                           
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
    String oauthVerifier = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");

    try 
    {
        AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(oauthVerifier);
        twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);

        String strAccessToken = accessToken.getToken())                                         
        String strTokenSecret =  accessToken.getTokenSecret();
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {                                       
        e.printStackTrace();
    }                               
}
```

**EDIT**

The above code should be placed in overridden method `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` of `WebView` which is used to authorize the user in your app.

Comment: I still confused. I use this code on button 's onclick() on activity. But you implement on WebView, dont you? Is is diferrent? I try to follow many tutorial today, but none of them works.

Comment: Yes, it is implemented using `WebView`. How you are authorizing with Twitter? Check your authorization process, you may find `AccessToken` and `TokenSecret` there.

Comment: I am not sure but you may look at https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/blob/master/twitter4j-examples/src/main/java/twitter4j/examples/tweets/UpdateStatus.java for help